# How many different random initializations should I perform with Lloyd's algorithm to obtain the optimal clustering with X% of confidence?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I use Lloyd's algorithm for clustering. Since it relies on a random initialization and Lloyd's  algorithm can get stuck in local optima of the k-means objective function, I have to run it several times.

How many different random initializations should I perform with Lloyd's algorithm to obtain the optimal clustering with X% of confidence? Or at least is there any rule of thumb advising for a decent number of random initializations?

Answer (score 1):

What good is finding the global optimum? You optimize some *number*, not the actual result.

k-means is based on **assumptions that won't hold on real data anyway**.

So it's not much more than a *heuristic* anyway.

Why find the gloabl optimum of a heuristic?

Comment: Well I would like to minimize the within-cluster sum of squares. Although it's indeed not a perfect metric, I prefer to be closer far from its global minimum.

Comment: If your data is so that k-means works reasonably well, a local minimum will be about as good as the global minimum. When you get very different results by running k-means multiple times, then your data does not fit the algorithm. (For example, you might be trying to use k-means on binary data. Don't.)